# Unable to Define Basic Functions in Python

Tags: python, function

I have just started to learn coding with Python. I was following instructions from the tutorials on **Coursera** and I am encountering an issue with defining the basic functions in Python.

My code is as follows:

```
>>> 
>>> def f(x):
    return x*2
f(3)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 
>>>
```

I am using the following Python package:

**Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin**

The same code displayed on the tutorial seems to be working fine wherein Python 3.2.3 is being used. Appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDLE Shell can only parse a single block of code at a time. The function definition and the function call are considered as different "blocks", so you need to separate them, by pressing Enter again after the function definition.

```
>>> def f(x):
    return x*2

>>> f(3)
6
```

Note that a "block" in this context is basically either just a stand-alone line of code, or any code that is indented and preceded by a line ending with a colon (`:`).

Like @Duncan mentioned, the blank line is only required in the interactive shell - it needs to know if there's still more to the block or you're done and you want the code to run. In a normal `.py` file, blank lines don't matter as the interpreter will know what to do because the code has already been written in it's entirety.

Comment: I know you imply this, but as the OP is confused it may be good to be completely explicit: you only need to put a blank link after the function definition when running Python in interactive mode (Idle or a console prompt). If (as you will usually do) you create a .py file and run that, it is entirely your choice whether or not to use a blank line.

Comment: What the hell? Man, I am already enjoying coding.... Simple hack, that's all that was needed. Thanks guys!! Now, back to the drawing board :)